# Why wont my code that is using Bootstrap add horizontal space between the rows of thumbnails?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, rows, spacing

I am making a thumbnail grid using bootstrap. The vertical spacing in between the images automatically appears, however the there is not horizontal spacing. the images are touching one another.

I have tried rearranging divs.

it should automatically have even space around every thumb nail

```
<!---jumbo-->
<div class ="container">
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1 class="display-4"><i class="fas fa-camera"></i> Image Gallery</h1>
        <p class="lead">This is a simple hero unit, a simple jumbotron-style component for calling extra attention to featured content or information.</p>
    </div>

<!--Images-->

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">
                <img src="web images/darkbutterfly.jpg"class="img-thumbnail">
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">
                <img src="web images/darkbutterfly.jpg" class="img-thumbnail">
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">
                <img src="web images/darkbutterfly.jpg" class="img-thumbnail">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">
                <img src="web images/darkbutterfly.jpg"class="img-thumbnail">
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">
                <img src="web images/darkbutterfly.jpg" class="img-thumbnail">
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">
                <img src="web images/darkbutterfly.jpg" class="img-thumbnail">
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">
                <img src="web images/darkbutterfly.jpg"class="img-thumbnail">
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">
                <img src="web images/darkbutterfly.jpg" class="img-thumbnail">
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">
                <img src="web images/darkbutterfly.jpg" class="img-thumbnail">
        </div>
    </div>




</div>
```

Comment: Without being able to see the code in action it's hard to troubleshoot. Could be as simple as the image being wider than your column declaration - which can be resolved by applying `.img-fluid` to your image class declarations.

Comment: Not seeing the issue: https://www.codeply.com/go/5AlOdrXSzm Do you mean there is no *vertical* spacing between the rows?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly then this should be the answer, check it out - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MRgdgX

```
<div class ="container">
<div class="jumbotron row">
  <div class="col-12">
    <h1 class="display-4"><i class="fas fa-camera"></i> Image Gallery</h1>
    <p class="lead">This is a simple hero unit, a simple jumbotron-style component for calling extra attention to featured content or information.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300" class="img-thumbnail">
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300" class="img-thumbnail">
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300" class="img-thumbnail">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300" class="img-thumbnail">
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300" class="img-thumbnail">
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300" class="img-thumbnail">
    </div>
</div>


<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300" class="img-thumbnail">
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300" class="img-thumbnail">
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300" class="img-thumbnail">
    </div>
</div>
```

```
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.jumbotron {
  margin: 0 1rem;
}
 img {
  display: flex;
  margin: 1rem;
}
```